# Filtering and ordering a query SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a database model for a Taxi recording system for a flask web application, using flask-sqlalchemy, and it looks like this:

```
class Taxi(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'taxis'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(32))
    area = db.Column(db.String(32))
    count = db.Column(db.Integer, default=0, index=True)
    last_dispatched = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

Ordinarily I would query the database model based on the area row doing this:

`abuja_taxis = Taxi.query.filter_by(area='Abuja').all()`

and order the database model based on the count row doing this:

`taxis = Taxi.query.order_by(Taxi.count).all()`

But I want to query the model by filtering based on the area row and also order that query based on the count row, but I can't order the results of the first filter since that is already a list.

Comment: You can chain methods: `Taxi.query.filter_by(area='Abuja').order_by(Taxi.count).all()`

Comment: Thank you. @PerunSS

Comment: How to do order_by DESC?

Answer (score 0):

For order query descending, try :

```
taxis = Taxi.query.order_by(Taxi.count.desc()).all()
```